# Throughput result on JMeter increase suddenly when using 100 threads

Tags: nginx, jmeter

I tested my local website using Nginx with PHP-FPM currently by using Apache JMeter. I try to do simple concurrent load testing on it.

Here is my test plan configuration, with 3 thread groups:-
Number of threads: 10, 50, 100
Ramp-up period: 0
Loop count: 1
In the test plan itself, I have 5 different pages represent 5 HTTP requests.

But then when I used 100 threads, the throughput (request/sec) is increased than when using 50 threads. I have run this many times, the result still same.

What is really happening here? I'm still amateur about JMeter. Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Possibility of increase in throughput on increasing the load is generally:

- **Increased error rate**, more errors will increase the throughput.

hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but which errors come from? From the Nginx or the JMeter itself?

Comment: Add "View Tree Listener" to your test plan, and share the error messages you are getting.

Comment: I already put View Results Tree listener to the test plan and from my observation there is no error message. Not even one error. The result exactly same, but it looks like the throughput increased only marginally not like before.

Comment: Follow these points and monitor the thoughput. By doing this we will make sure the network we are using is not already congested:   

**Use LAN connection on laptop/PC and Not Wifi**, 
**Execute Load/performance Test during off-peak office hours**

Comment: gone through your question again. according to your test plan when your using 10 threads, you are sending 50 requests/sec. when your using 50 threads, you are sending 250 requests/sec. when your using 100 threads, you are sending 500 requests/sec. looking at this it is obvious that your throughput is going to vary. but if it is consistent in providing the same results +/-, that means the system/application behavior is like that, unless it changes substantially. If your application/system processes 10 requests/sec but in the last second execution it processes 20 requests/sec, throughput=20/sec.